# Minecraft launch error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, graphics, minecraft

Whenever I try to run the latest version of Minecraft, I get this error (I'm new to using VPS servers)

> GLFW error 65542: GLX: GLX extension not found.
>   Please make sure you have up-to-date drivers (see aka.ms/mcdriver for instructions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run Minecraft on VPS servers before they don't have any graphic card.